# Rotating Image view by clicking on the button

Tags: java, android

I want to rotate my image view by clicking in my button.
I want this:
when user click in the button , rotate image view 90 degree.
when click in my button again ,rotate image view 180 degree.
when click in my button again ,rotate image view 270 degree.
when click in my button again ,rotate image view 0 degree.
and this continue like this ...
I can rotate my image view correctly just one time with 90 degree by this code :

```
        mImageView.setRotation(0);
```

and by this I can rotate to 90 degree and return it to 0 degree.

```
float deg = (mImageView.getRotation() == 90F) ? 0F : 90F;
    mImageView.animate().rotation(deg).setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
```

how I can do this?

Comment: Check this link also you may get the answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/18016331/4069985

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When click a button rotate image clockwise in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18016126/when-click-a-button-rotate-image-clockwise-in-android)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write down below code on your `Button` click

```
imageView.setRotation(imageView.getRotation() + 90);
```

Initially and after completing whole circle rotation set `0 rotation` value to `ImageView`

Answer (score 0):

```
private void rotate(float degree) {
    final RotateAnimation rotateAnim = new RotateAnimation(0.0f, degree,
            RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
            RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);

    rotateAnim.setDuration(0);
    rotateAnim.setFillAfter(true);
    imgview.startAnimation(rotateAnim);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a rotation animation and set it to **Reverse** **Repeat** the animation, This way view will rotate to **desired** angle and will goes back to **initial** angle immediately:

```
ImageView diskView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView3);

// Create an animation instance
Animation an = new RotateAnimation(0.0f, 360.0f, pivotX, pivotY);

// Set the animation's parameters
an.setDuration(10000);               // duration in ms
an.setRepeatCount(1);                // -1 = infinite repeated
an.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE); // reverses each repeat
an.setFillAfter(true);               // keep rotation after animation

// Aply animation to image view
diskView.setAnimation(an);
diskView.startAnimation();
```